# Threejs running in frame on ios error

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, three.js

I have this application running here:
https://afternoon-cliffs-70079.herokuapp.com/
and it works totally fine on the computer as well as on my galaxy 8, however the problem is that the application fails to run on ios. I have tested a few scenarios and have limited it down to the fact that what I am doing is running the application in an iframe (this is done so that the application can be full screened on one page, then when a user clicks on a menu item they are sent to another page without breaking the full screen). Is this a known issue for how ios handle iframes? The problem appears on both safari and chrome for ios.

EDIT: 
One thing I did notice is that a lot of people do seem to be having problems with iframes in general on ios. Not this specific problem, but other problems.

Comment: While running on a iPhone, the canvas's height keeps increasing.

Comment: I see. You mean the iframes height? Or the canvas inside the iframe? So I am using css to keep the size of the canvas to be 100%, but ofc that is irrelevant to the actual "height" of the iframe. I just reread and thought about what you said. Let me play around with it and see what I can.

Comment: The actual iframe height is changing. interesting. If you are aware of a solution that would be greatly appreciated. I will look into this :)

Comment: Im adding a temporary solution for now where on ios it ignores the resize call.